# How to "reuse" a stream?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, pipe

I wrote a small client and server app to learn how to use pipes.  In each app I originally had the streams in a using block and I quickly found out that when the using block was finished and it disposed of the stream, it also disposed my pipes.

I got rid of the using blocks and made member variables for the streams.  Now my problem is that when I call the ReadLine function on the StreamReader in the client it doesn't continue until my server app is closed (or more specifically, until the StreamWriter is disposed of).

It seems strange that I would have to create a new stream (and by extension a new pipe as well since every time the stream is closed it disposes of the pipe too) for each message I want to send.  What do I need to change?

Server Code:

```
class PipeServer
{
    NamedPipeServerStream _pipeServer;
    StreamWriter _sw;

    public PipeServer(string pipeName)
    {
        _pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.Out);
        _pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
        _sw = new StreamWriter(_pipeServer) { AutoFlush = true };
    }

    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        _sw.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
public delegate void MessageReadEventHandler(string message);

class PipeClient
{
    public event MessageReadEventHandler MessageReadEvent;

    NamedPipeClientStream _pipeClient;
    StreamReader _sr;

    public PipeClient(string pipeName)
    {
        _pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.In);
        _pipeClient.Connect();
        _sr = new StreamReader(_pipeClient);
    }

    public void ReadMessages()
    {
        string temp;

        while ((temp = _sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            if (MessageReadEvent != null)
                MessageReadEvent(temp);
    }
}
```

Server form contains one text box and has the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PipeClient pClient = new PipeClient("testpipe");

    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pClient.MessageReadEvent += o => { textBox1.Text = o; };
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pClient.ReadMessages();
    }
}
```

Client form has one text box and has the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PipeServer pServer = new PipeServer("testpipe");

    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void ServerTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pServer.WriteMessage(ServerTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to fire an event every time a message is sent, and I want the pipe to stay open and listen continually for messages.

Comment: Pipes can operate in two modes.  Stream is the default, sure sounds like you need PipeTransmissionMode.Message instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks.  I just tried changing the mode to Message but it seems to act just the same.  I don't entirely understand what needs to be done to cause the client to return from _sr.ReadLine().  It waits there until the stream on the server has been disposed.  Seems like there should be a way to make it continue without having to close the StreamWriter though?  (Flush doesn't seem to do it.)

Comment: @HansPassant Also, the docs say that the message mode "Indicates that data in the pipe is transmitted and read as a stream of messages."  But I'm not even sure what 'message' is.  Doesn't seem to be a class in this namespace called Message or anything like that...

Comment: @Brandon: Message, aka datagram mode means that boundaries of individual writes are preserved and correspond 1:1 to reads.  In stream mode, one read can get data from many writes in sequence, or vice-versa.

Comment: @BenVoigt How would I take advantage of that?  I.e. I just changed my code so it writes a message length followed by another write of the message in a char array instead of using the ReadLine method.  This fixed my problem, but as you can see I am managing some details myself that it sounds like I should not have to were I correctly using the messaging method...  any good links you could point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to give a proper answer to your question I would have to have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that I can run and fiddle with. Unfortunately, the code you posted isn't one. So, the next best thing I can do is give you a pointer to the direction in which you should look to solve your problem: the NamedPipeServerStream() function has many overloads, some of which allow many more parameters to be specified. You should pick one of those overloads and try specifying more parameters, fiddling with their values, in order to get your code to work. One of them, rather crucial, I would say, is the pipe transmission mode: byte or message. Try specifying 'message' for that one.

**EDIT**

Okay, I think I see two problems with the code posted:

1. WriteLine() most probably uses buffered I/O, which means that you would have to issue lots of WriteLine()s before the buffer would fill up and be sent to the client. When you terminate the server, its buffer is flushed, that's why the messages used to arrive to the client at that moment.
2. The tight blocking ReadLine() loop on the client probably does not allow the client to do any repainting, so setting the text of the textbox to the content of the message received probably does not appear to have any effect. (Unless setting the text property forces a repaint, I am not sure it does, it should not.) That could be solved by either following `textBox1.Text = o;` with `textBox1.Update();` or by embedding a `System.WinForms.Application.DoEvents();` call inside your tight loop.

Please note that you have the Server form and the Client form mixed up; that's one of the reasons why a real SSCCE (a listing of code known to compile) is useful.

I would say, *welcome to the wonderful world of windows named pipes programming*. It is not simple, and it is not easy. MSDN has a good sample here: [How to: Use Named Pipes to Communicate Between Processes over a Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx) but as extensive as it may seem, it is still quite elementary. In reality you will need to either use asynchronous (non-blocking) I/O or utilize the thread pool (System.Threading.ThreadPool) if you want your server to be able to handle an arbitrary number of simultaneously connected clients.

Comment: Oh, and, I assure you that it is of course possible to use named pipes without having to re-create the client pipe for each message. So, "how to reuse the stream" is a rather unfortunate choice for the question. A better choice would be "how can I get the damned named pipes to work?"

Comment: Create two WinForms apps and add a text box to the default form in each.  Then add the code in my post (notice I added the form code) and you'll have your SSCCE (after adding appropriate usings, of course).  The chief problem is that the client doesn't return from _sr.ReadLine() until the stream on the Server has been disposed.  How to make it read without having to dispose the stream on the server side is the question...

Comment: Mike, thanks for your help.  I think my setting AutoFlush = true addresses your first point, or am I misunderstanding that property?  In looking for more clues to answer my problem I finally ran across a page where I found what was equivalent to what I ultimately wanted my source to look like: http://www.benday.com/2008/06/22/playing-with-nets-named-pipe-streams-with-net-to-net-and-win32-to-net-samples/.  So far it seems to be working great!

Comment: Wh00ps, you are right, `AutoFlush = true` should be taking care of the buffering issue.